# Other ETFs of world bonds and stocks (Alternatives to VT and BND)?

Tags: etf

For simpler investing, my grandfather wants to buy only 2 ETFs: one that holds only stocks worldwide and one that holds only bonds worldwide. To avoid commission fees, he doesn't want to buy a group of ETFs when he can just buy an aggregate ETF.

He has found only VT (Vanguard Total World Stock) and BND (Vanguard Total Bond Market ETF). Are these 2 the only options? The quote prices for both are above $60 USD/share.
He prefers an ETF that trades in Canadian dollars and is cheaper per share.

Comment: BND is not world Bonds, it is US Bonds. Share price has nothing to do with "expensive" or not. If an ETF is $60 and you want to invest $3000, you buy 50 shares. If an ETF is $30 and you want to invest $3000, you buy 100 shares. Share price is meaningless in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another choice I like, iShares JPMorgan USD Emerging Markets Bond (EMB)

Here is the world ETFs

```
BNDX - Vanguard Total International Bond ETF
IGOV - iShares International Treasury Bond
PICB - PowerShares International Corp Bd ETF
```

Comment: Thank you for the last 3. Would you mind revealing how you found them?

Comment: if you have Fidelity/E-Trade/TDAmeritrade accounts, you can easily filter ETFs by their Sector/Geography